# PHP's datetime() object discrepancy

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

Oddly, this morning, my `DateTime()` object decided to change the current year to `+3 years` for some reason ( from 2013 to 2016) . At first, I thought it was the server playing up for that amount of time , but through my software logs, I found out that `time()` and `date()` functions were showing the right date and time from the server when this odd behavior  was happening. 
Everything is back to normal now  as the year change happened for a brief amount of time ( cannot say for how long)
Anything I should be aware of the `DateTime()` object ???
Should I just shift to using `date()` and `time()` functions to display for current `timestamp()` ?

I just want to clarify this :
In one of my functions, I have the end date set to Current + 3 years

```
$this->date = new DateTime();
$mapping->end = $this->date->add(new DateInterval('P3Y'));
```

Now I'm guessing the `$this->date` object would be set to Current `+3 years` for the whole time of the execution if it hasn't been modified at any other stage. Am I correct in saying this? If this is true, then yes, it was my predecessors code that messed it up!

Comment: At least include the exact code that produced this problem and proof so we can rule out that it's your fault. Also include all available information about system versions etc. If you suspect a bug, provide a test case.

Comment: In general: no, this is unlikely to be the cause of DateTime. It's more likely something with your code or the server settings.